# contrasts effects in statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

url = "https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv"
hsb2 = pd.read_table(url, delimiter=",")
hsb2.head()
hsb2.head()
Out[4]: 
    id  female  race  ses  schtyp  prog  read  write  math  science  socst
0   70       0     4    1       1     1    57     52    41       47     57
1  121       1     4    2       1     3    68     59    53       63     61
```

I have two categorical variables of interests (race and female) and I would like to compute the t stat of the average `read` score for each possible combination of these variables. Of course, I can get this information indirectly by using the `C()` notation in statsmodels to regress `write` on the full interaction between these categorical variables:

```
mod = ols("write ~ C(race)*C(female)", data=hsb2)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  write   R-squared:                       0.171
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.140
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     5.642
Date:                Fri, 25 Aug 2023   Prob (F-statistic):           6.16e-06
Time:                        11:02:32   Log-Likelihood:                -714.39
No. Observations:                 200   AIC:                             1445.
Df Residuals:                     192   BIC:                             1471.
Df Model:                           7                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
===============================================================================================
                                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                      44.3846      2.437     18.210      0.000      39.577      49.192
C(race)[T.2]                   11.2821      5.629      2.004      0.046       0.180      22.385
C(race)[T.3]                    2.6154      4.120      0.635      0.526      -5.511      10.742
C(race)[T.4]                    6.9095      2.660      2.597      0.010       1.663      12.156
C(female)[T.1]                  4.5245      3.600      1.257      0.210      -2.577      11.626
C(race)[T.2]:C(female)[T.1]    -1.3161      6.954     -0.189      0.850     -15.032      12.400
C(race)[T.3]:C(female)[T.1]    -2.6783      5.471     -0.490      0.625     -13.470       8.113
C(race)[T.4]:C(female)[T.1]     0.6749      3.886      0.174      0.862      -6.990       8.340
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        6.095   Durbin-Watson:                   1.906
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.047   Jarque-Bera (JB):                5.710
Skew:                          -0.356   Prob(JB):                       0.0576
Kurtosis:                       2.578   Cond. No.                         23.2
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

However, In the regressino output I would like to see the full contrasts effects (without the intercept), that is the average score for each combination of female and race without having to add the main effects and the interactions myself.

Can I do this in statsmodels?

Comment: without reestimating the models, the current options are to use t_test, e.g. `t_test("Intercept + C(race)[T.2], Intercept + C(race)[T.2]")` or `predict`, `get_prediction`, that has a dataframe as exog with observations for each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

remove the intercept, and regress on the interaction only.

```
mod = ols("write ~  0+C(race):C(female)", data=hsb2)
print(res.summary())
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  write   R-squared:                       0.171
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.140
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     5.642
Date:                Sat, 26 Aug 2023   Prob (F-statistic):           6.16e-06
Time:                        11:31:36   Log-Likelihood:                -714.39
No. Observations:                 200   AIC:                             1445.
Df Residuals:                     192   BIC:                             1471.
Df Model:                           7                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
===========================================================================================
                              coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C(race)[1]:C(female)[0]    44.3846      2.437     18.210      0.000      39.577      49.192
C(race)[2]:C(female)[0]    55.6667      5.074     10.971      0.000      45.659      65.674
C(race)[3]:C(female)[0]    47.0000      3.322     14.150      0.000      40.448      53.552
C(race)[4]:C(female)[0]    51.2941      1.066     48.131      0.000      49.192      53.396
C(race)[1]:C(female)[1]    48.9091      2.650     18.458      0.000      43.683      54.135
C(race)[2]:C(female)[1]    58.8750      3.107     18.949      0.000      52.747      65.003
C(race)[3]:C(female)[1]    48.8462      2.437     20.040      0.000      44.039      53.654
C(race)[4]:C(female)[1]    56.4935      1.002     56.409      0.000      54.518      58.469
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        6.095   Durbin-Watson:                   1.906
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.047   Jarque-Bera (JB):                5.710
Skew:                          -0.356   Prob(JB):                       0.0576
Kurtosis:                       2.578   Cond. No.                         5.07
==============================================================================
```